# При переходе на другую страницу расширение хрома перестаёт работать

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, html, chrome-extension, вконтакте

Делаю расширение для хрома, которое добавляет во вкладку "Прикрепить" ещё одну кнопку при написании поста вк.

Вот мой манифест:

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome extension",
    "version": "0.1",

    "icons": {
        "128": "128x128.png"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://vk.com/*",
        "https://vk.com/*"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["http://vk.com/*","https://vk.com/*"],
      "css": ["style.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [ "img.png" ]
}
```

Вот пример кода из script.js:

```
    window.onload = function(){
    $( ".add_media_type_1_audio" ).after( "<a class='add_media_type_26_audio add_media_item activate_modal' name='code_window' style='background-image: url("+chrome.extension.getURL('img.png')+"); background-position: 3px 3px;'><nobr>Кнопка</nobr></a>" );
    // тут остальные действия с этой кнопкой
  }
```

Когда вводишь сразу ссылку на группу, то всё отлично отображается, но стоить перейти в любую вкладку ("Моя страница", например) и через "Мои группы" зайти в нужную нам, то перестаёт отображаться. Ну, в общем, как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить:

```
"permissions": ["activeTab"]
```

Если не поможет, то копайте код глубже, либо на новой странице что-то меняется, либо оно появляется не сразу и т.д. Например, можно через `setTimeout` попробовать.

Comment: Ничего не работает, пробовал всё что можно. В итоге сделал запуск из контекстного меню. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Тогда onload должен один раз при открытие сайта vk.com запускать setInterval(), а там уже проверка на существование элемента каждую н-ую секунду. Такой вариант меня всегда бесил, но он всегда работал.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что сайт vk при внутренних переходах не редиректит пользователя на новую страницу, а, используя AJAX, запрашивает контент страницы с сервера, и подменяет им контент текущей страницы. URL в адресной строке обновляется с помощью history API.
По этой причине window.onload не вызывается при переходах.

Comment: Я это уже понял, пробовал использовать Mutation Observer, но не прокатило.